# Problem with image showing on some pages but not showing on others

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

[image: This picture shows that the image doesnt show on other pages, and i showed the network tab aswell]i recently ran into a problem where my image i saved on the server shows on a page but does not show on other pages of the site. I have searched for two days now but to no avail, i wonder what is causing the problem, i use express for my server and react js for my client, please if anyone can figure out exactly why this code is not working, i will be extremely grateful.

```
// get a product by id (API endpoint)
// @@@ - public
router.get('/find/:productId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.productId);

    if (!product) {
      return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Product not found' }] });
    }

    res.json(product);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});


// get product by id (React-redux fetching the api)
export const getItemById = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(clearItem());
  dispatch(loading());

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/products/find/${productId}`);

    dispatch({ type: GET_ITEM_BY_ID, payload: res.data });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: ITEM_ERROR, payload: 'Error occured' });
  }
};

//code for fecthing the images (this is a dumb prop and the data gotten from the data has been passed into it)
const ItemImages = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Carousel>
        {item.productImages.map((img) => {
          return (
            <div key={img._id}>
              <img src={img.image.data} alt='product' />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
      <h1>{item && item.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The first picture shows that the image does load on one page
the second image shows that the image doesnt load on another and i showed the network tab as well

[[image: enter image description here][1]]

Comment: What is the result of this line  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.productId); ?
what is the value of product here, can you add in the question

Comment: That line of code gets a single product from the database based on the id that is in the url

Comment: Is the object returned populated with anything? Are you actually getting the bytes you need? Have you tried hitting your endpoint with a tool like Postman? It doesn't seem like a frontend problem to me by just looking at your code you've posted here.

Comment: Hi, yes I hit endpoint and I get the data, on postman and everywhere, I just don’t know what the problem is, I might abandon the project all together